# $pull operator doesn't work when used with loopback

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop, loopback

I am trying to update a document and remove a row from nested array.
Here is how it looks:

```
await app.models.orgadmin.updateAll({}, {$pull: {dashboard: {site_name:'testing'}}});
```

This doesn't work with loopback's updateAll method. However when I try to execute this in mongo shell, it works fine!

Banging my head around this for last 2 days :(

Comment: You have `allowExtendedOperators` set, correct?  Also post your debug string https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-mongodb

Comment: yes it is set..

Comment: Plese use only pull instead of $pull

await app.models.orgadmin.updateAll({}, {pull: {dashboard: {site_name:'testing'}}});

Comment: In loopback i use in query like

 Model.find({ where: { id: { in: feedIds } } }....

Comment: Is it solved. I am facing the similar issue.